# Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

## I'm trying to set up a function to flip me over : ephemeralKeys

#### Error returned by firestoreCloud

```
  Unhandled error TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
        at exports.createEphemeralKey.functions.https.onCall (/srv/index.js:28:32)
        at func (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:272:32)
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

#### My stripe statement

const stripe = require('stripe')('MySecretApi');

### My CreateEphemeralKeys function

```
exports.createEphemeralKey = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
    const customerId = data.customer_id;
    const stripeVersion = data.stripe_version;
    console.log(stripeVersion);
    console.log(customerId);
    return stripe.ephemeralKeys({ customer: customerId }, { stripe_version: stripeVersion }).then((key) => {
        return key;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', ' Unable to create ephemeral key: ' + err);
    });
}));
```

"" Class STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider  ""

```
class _StripeApi: NSObject, STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider {
    
    func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
        
        let data = [
            "stripe_version": apiVersion,
            "customer_id" : UserService.user.stripeId
        ]
                
        Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createEphemeralKey").call(data) { (result, error) in
            
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let key = result?.data as? [String: Any] else {
                completion(nil, nil)
                return
            }
            
            completion(key, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, which language are you using? JavaScript or TypeScript?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your interest in my problem.

I'm using the JavaScript

Comment: Ok, I have two questions: why are you using `__awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* ()` and are you sure that `ephemeralKeys` is a method of the Stripe Node.js Library?

Comment: I call my backEnd from my IOS application with STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider to ask the server to generate an EphemeralKey.

I'll add my class in the post

Comment: It is not clear for me what you exactly do. Your Cloud Function is a [callable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) one, you should call it from you iOS app as explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function. In your CF you need to use methods from the Stripe **Node.js** Library.

Comment: Your code in your iOS app seems correct. What seems not correct is your code in the CF. See my two questions above: why are you using `__awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* ()` and are you sure that `ephemeralKeys` is a method of the Stripe Node.js Library?

Comment: no I'm not sure it's part of the stripe library, for the back end I wanted to reproduce a tutorial.

I'm gonna try to go through the stripe documentation.

Comment: I would also suggest you write your Cloud Function like `exports.createEphemeralKey = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {...});` without `awaiter` see the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function

Answer (score 0):

`stripe.ephemeralKeys` isn't a function. You want `stripe.ephemeralKeys.create`. See the docs here: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#ephemeral-key